# OSError: [WinError 126] JVM DLL not found - can't understand the problem

Tags: java, python, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to use KoNLPy (a Python package for natural language processing (NLP) of the Korean language, you can find it here: https://konlpy.org/en/latest/) to create a web-app as a final project for an online course I'm taking (I'm quite new to programming). I have followed every step from the explanation (https://konlpy.org/en/latest/install/#id2), using Windows 10. I also checked that all programs run on a 64 run version, but still, when I run my app on VS code to just check if it's working I run into this error:

OSError: [WinError 126] JVM DLL not found: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.0.1\bin\server\jvm.dll

However, I have that file, and I also set JAVA_HOME as instructed. I also tried adding the file to PATH, and then to eliminate any reference to java (in path) and only have %JAVA_HOME%\jdk\bin as I read online that it could be a solution...but that also didn't work :(

Does anyone know what I can do or what could be the problem? Could it be an issue of Visual Studio code?
Thank you so much, any advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the JAVA_HOME with double escape:

"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.0.1"

Check that jvm.dll has execution permissions.

Install pywin32.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I tried and it didn't work, but I later found out that there was a problem with the way I had installed Python and with how VS code was using it....but thank you anyway for helping out! :)

Comment: @bebeamur - So have your question been solved? You can post your solution under this question.